# SQL: How do I filter (WHERE) a joined (ON) table in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables (users and posts) and I want to write out all posts (among other things) by one user. I'm thinking I should use a JOIN and WHERE but I get an error for using WHERE.

This is my code:

```
SELECT username, post, joinDate, title, info FROM users 
    WHERE userId='18' 
    JOIN posts ON users.userId=posts.userId 
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

I'm new to this and perhaps there is a better way but I can't figure it out atm.
Thankful for all answers!

Comment: `WHERE` must come after `JOIN`

Comment: move `WHERE userId='18'` after the join statement and before order by

Answer (score 5):

The JOIN clause comes before the WHERE clause, after the FROM clause. First you join together all the tables you need, then you do your filtering with WHERE. Like this:

```
SELECT username, post, joinDate, title, info
FROM users 
JOIN posts ON users.userId=posts.userId 
WHERE users.userId='18'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: I get "#1052 - Column 'userId' in where clause is ambiguous" when I do that, what might be causing this?

Comment: You can try with `JOIN posts USING(userId)`

Comment: You need to specify your table alias before any column names in the WHERE clause that are contained in more than one of the tables that you have joined together.

WHERE users.userID = '18'

Comment: Change to `WHERE users.userId='18'` to avoid ambiguity.
`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try like below

```
    SELECT u.*,p.*
    FROM users u JOIN posts p ON u.userId=p.userId
    WHERE u.userId=18      
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

`where` will be after  `join` and 18 is int datatype value so not need single quote for this and use alias for avoiding ambigous column name

Comment: Why? Selecting * is always a bad idea, do not recommend it. Why do you think that aliasing with single letters is going to help?

Comment: @Dharman i used alias name of table that is not like * selection so du you think table alias name .* and * is same ?

Comment: @Dharman so before downvoting you have to clear about your idea

Comment: I made 2 points. First is that you should avoid `SELECT *` always. Second is that the single letter alias is not needed and does not help with anything; it makes it more difficult to read.

Comment: @Dharman here in SO the user who provide answer mostly for each question of answer related to sql always use signle letter alias name in his query do you  know why? because here most people submit subset or sample of their real life problem so it is mandatory to inform OP's what he need to solve this problem not all in all hope you got my point

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT username, post, joinDate, title, info
FROM users 
JOIN posts ON users.userId=posts.userId and users.userId='18'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

if `userId` is in `users` table then YES you can use `where userId='18'`.

If `userId` is in `posts` table then it should be `userId='18'` be in join part.

Comment: You missed the point and you answer is creating more confusion for beginners like OP.